# Переход по ссылке, при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать в android приложении, что бы после нажатия на кнопку открывался браузер или Google Play и осуществлялся переход по ссылке.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавьте в обработчик нажатия на вашу кнопку старт `Activity` со специальным `Intent`, содержащим вашу ссылку. Вот так:

```
Intent browserIntent = new 
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mylink.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```